# Composition of regular functions not necessarily regular

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, functions

I define regular function in the following way:

Let $f: U \to R^n$ a $C^1$ function, where $U \subset R^m$ is an open set. Then, $f$ is regular if for every $x \in U$, $rank(D_f(x)) = min(m,n)$.

Is there an example of two regular functions, that their composition is not regular?

I somehow struggle to find such example. What I did got is that neither of them can be a diffeomorphism. So maybe we need to look at functions that are not injective or that their inverse doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can already see the problem in linear functions. Consider functions $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R^2}$ and $g: \mathbb{R^2} \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x) = (x,0)$ and $g(x,y) = y$ so that $g \circ f(x) = 0$, even though both are regular.

Under the additional hypothesis that both maps are surjective, or that both maps are injective, the composition of linear regular maps will be regular. Think of how you'd generalize this to nonlinear differentiable functions.